# Updating multiple displays from a single machine

Tags: external-display

My use case is similar to the lobby display of a small gym: three displays, each with a different level of refresh:

```
1. The monthly calendar
2. This hour's schedule of events
3. Streaming video of the current activities
```

The advice that I have been given so far amounts to having a different computer to support each display.  Ideally, I would want to maintain (e.g., assign and change) all of these feeds from a single machine, but not mirror that display (e.g., so that computer could be used for other tasks--even better if this is possible on a desktop computer with windows).

Can this be done, and if so, how?

If not, what's the next-best alternative--and how should I be describing this problem to get more information?

Thanks!

Edit:

How far are the displays?  Probably less than 25 feet away from base computer; it would be possible to have a wired connection, although avoiding that might be easier to set up (e.g., to avoid having to drill holes in walls/floor).

What would be used for displays?  I'm flexible here to use whatever works best--something like a wall-mounted 20-30" LCD.

Comment: This can easily be done from one PC, assuming the displays arent to far away.  If you were to use one PC, how far would each of the displays be?

Comment: Also, what would you be using for displays?

Comment: Some video cards have as many as 6 different connector on them.  Given the trivial data you want to do display it will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Step 1 gather all the equipment
     2  3 monitors whatever size and see what connectors they have.
     3  Find adapters for the video card.  Most video cards have a variety of plugs
         including  dvi,vga,hdmi, and display port.
     4  Goto monoprice.com and buy the correct cables and adapters.
     5  Drill holes and run the cable. (times 3)
     6  Screw LCD mounting brackets to the wall. (times 3)
     7  Find a nearby outlet plug into wall (times 3)
     8  By the time you get here they should all be mounted and the cables run back to the pc (times 3)
     9  Get out the adapters plug everything into the video card
     10 Launch Windows (in Win 7) Right Click desktop and select screen resolution
     11 Select Extend my monitor onto other display, but do not select clone screen
      You now have 3 separate and usable desktops.  When your mouse cursor crosses the right edge of the screen it will move to monitor #2 and then monitor #3.

     Desktop 1  Launch Google Chrome open google calendar select Month view
             2  google calendar "day view"
             3  Launch VLC and have it display your live stream
```

Load all calendar events into a google calendar.  Google calendars have many advantages.  I used them to schedule 12+ rooms.  Each room is a calendar in a different color.  You can sent out invites via google and your clients can accept them or not.  You can view in real-time the enrollment.